# Replace String in filename in Bulk using MS DOS/CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I have a folder "Main" inside that i have multiple folders "foo","fooxyz" and so on, each folder has around 10-20k files.

I wanted to replace a string in all the files. so basically i had to deal with For /R in "Main", I tried the following code with the help of questions asked but i am not sure what needs to be done exactly.

```
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "Pattern=.jpg"
Set "Replace=_main.jpg"

For /R C:\Main\ %%# in ("*.jpg") Do (
    Set "File=%%~nx#"
    Ren "%%#" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)
```

If my code can be corrected well and good if not kindly point me in the right direction.

Comment: Use `ECHO Ren "%%#" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"` for debugging purposes and run the script: you would see correct output. You can remove `ECHO` then and run your bulk rename script really.

Comment: why not use `ren "%%#" "%%~n#_main%%~x#"` ?

Comment: Josefz - thanks for that, was able to find and solve the problem.

Comment: Stephan - i am pretty much a newbie in cmd so i search on stack for answers and modify them as per the requirement, cant code that much in cmd myself :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [search and replace file names - bug fix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702156/search-and-replace-file-names-bug-fix)